# Does DexClassloader still work in Android 9 Pie?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, dexclassloader

I've been using DexClassloader to load classes at runtime in Android 5.1 Lollipop, and I seem to recall there's some problem with it in Android 9 Pie...

But I can't find any mention of it now. Perhaps there's no problem and it still works?

Maybe I'm getting mixed up with android 10 Q, where I understand there definitely is a problem in executing downloaded binaries (which is an issue for [termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1072)), for security reasons. If google is doing that, it would make sense to also prevent execution of downloaded java code.

Does DexClassloder still work in Android 9 Pie? Thanks for any help!